# Set Authorization/Content-Type headers when call HTTPClient.PostAsync

Tags: c#, netsuite

Where can I set headers to REST service call when using simple HTTPClient?

I do :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"id", "111"},
    {"amount", "22"}
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var uri = new Uri(@"https://some.ns.restlet.uri");

var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

UPD

Headers I want to add:

```
{
    "Authorization": "NLAuth nlauth_account=5731597_SB1, nlauth_email=xxx@xx.com, nlauth_signature=Pswd1234567, nlauth_role=3",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

Should I do the following?

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "NLAuth nlauth_account=5731597_SB1, nlauth_email=xxx@xx.com, nlauth_signature=Pswd1234567, nlauth_role=3","Content-Type":"application/json");
```

Comment: Are you looking for this `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");`

Comment: What headers you're looking to Add? There are different ways to add different header for example the Accept Header `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding headers when using httpClient.GetAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801195/adding-headers-when-using-httpclient-getasync)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158250/how-to-post-using-httpclient-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded/57658305#57658305).

Comment: The question is different, but the answer in the original duplicate applies for GET as well and it has more upvotes by a magnitude.

Answer (score 48):

The way to add headers is as follows:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");
```

Or if you want some custom header:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("HEADERNAME", "HEADERVALUE");
```

This answer has SO responses already, see below:

- [Adding headers when using httpClient.GetAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801195/adding-headers-when-using-httpclient-getasync)
- [Setting Authorization Header of HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient)

UPDATE

Seems you are adding two headerrs; authorization and content type.

```
string authValue = "NLAuth nlauth_account=5731597_SB1,nlauth_email=xxx@xx.com, nlauth_signature=Pswd1234567, nlauth_role=3";
string contentTypeValue = "application/json";

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(authValue);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", contentTypeValue);
```

Comment: I have updated question body with header I need to add. I suppose I should use Authorization header?

Comment: Check the answer from Alaa Masoud here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039450/adding-authorization-to-the-headers for more details.

Comment: Microsoft docs [advise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/) `HttpClient` to be a singleton unless you have a very good reason for it not to be. I wonder if the "Default" part of the "DefaultRequestHeaders" implies that headers can also be supplied on a per-request basis without mutating state of the client...

Answer (score 15):

I know this was asked a while ago, but Juan's solution didn't work for me.

(Also, pretty sure this question is duplicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310891/authorization-header-in-restlet-netsuite-web-service-call?rq=1).)

The method that finally worked was to use HttpClient with [HttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage(v=vs.118).aspx) and [HttpResponseMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx).

Also note that this is using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) from Newtonsoft.

```
    using System;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    namespace NetsuiteConnector
    {
        class Netsuite
        {

            public void RunHttpTest()
            {
                Task t = new Task(TryConnect);
                t.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to NS...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            private static async void TryConnect()
            {
                // dummy payload
                String jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                    new NewObj() {
                        Name = "aname",
                        Email = "someone@somewhere.com"
                    }
                );

                string auth = "NLAuth nlauth_account=123456,nlauth_email=youremail@somewhere.com,nlauth_signature=yourpassword,nlauth_role=3";

                string url  = "https://somerestleturl";
                var uri     = new Uri(@url);

                HttpClient c = new HttpClient();
                    c.BaseAddress = uri;
                    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", auth);
                    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
                req.Content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await c.SendAsync(req);
                httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                HttpContent httpContent = httpResponseMessage.Content;
                string responseString = await httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync();

                Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            }
        }

        class NewObj
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers do not work if you are using an HttpClientFactory, and [here's some reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) why you should. With an HttpClientFactory the HttpMessages are reused from a pool, so setting default headers should be reserved for headers that will be used in every request.

If you just want to add a content-type header you can use the alternate `PostAsJsonAsync` or `PostAsXmlAsync`.

```
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("account/update", model);
```

Unfortunately I don't have a better solution for adding authorization headers than this.

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), $"Bearer {bearer}");
```

Answer (score 3):

On dotnet core 3.1 trying to run the top answer:

```cs
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-msdownload");
```

threw an exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.`

What worked for me was to instead set [`HttpContent.Headers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.headers?view=net-6.0#System_Net_Http_HttpContent_Headers) -> [`HttpContentHeaders.ContentType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders.contenttype?view=net-6.0#System_Net_Http_Headers_HttpContentHeaders_ContentType) property with a [`MediaTypeHeaderValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.mediatypeheadervalue?view=net-6.0) value:

```cs
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(path));
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-msdownload");
var post = client.PostAsync(myUrl, content);
```

Answer (score 2):

I [prefer to cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/) the httpClient so I avoid setting headers which could affect other requests and use [SendAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=net-7.0#system-net-http-httpclient-sendasync(system-net-http-httprequestmessage))

```
var postRequest = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, url);
postRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "NLAuth nlauth_account=5731597_SB1, nlauth_email=xxx@xx.com, nlauth_signature=Pswd1234567, nlauth_role=3");

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(postRequest);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Note, the `Content-Type: application/json` header would conflict with the `FormUrlEncodedContent()` used in your code sample, as it already adds the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header.