# HttpClient Get call returning statuscode 401 unauthoriszed In C#

Tags: c#, winapi, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I'm trying to make a HttpClient Call through C# by adding some headers. The request is working fine by throwing the empty result as expected with 200 status code. But the same is not working in C# code. My code is like below :

```
public static Response TestAbcAPICall()
        {
            Response response = new Response();

            try
            {
                var endpoint = "https:/abc.com/path/?script=435&deploy=1&type=vendor&id=9797";

                
                using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(endpoint);
                    //way - 1 Adding Authorization header

                    var authenticationHeaderValue = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "NLAuth nlauth_account=1249484_SKB1, nlauth_email=restletuser1@org.in, nlauth_signature=Breaths123!, nlauth_role=4444");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authenticationHeaderValue;

                    // Adding contennt-type header
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    var getTask = client.GetAsync(endpoint);
                    getTask.Wait();
                    var result = getTask.Result;

                    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var RESULTS = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        //response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(RESULTS);
                        if (response.flag)
                        {
                            response.flag = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            response.flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.message = ex.Message;
                response.flag = false;
            }

            return response;
        }
```

Reference ARC worrking with 200 status Image : [image: Working with ARC]

Comment: client.BaseAddress Is not needed to be set, you already have a full address.

Comment: @Alen.Toma Yes of course Thank you, Commented it. still facing the same..

Comment: The working code is using HTTPS (secure).  Are you getting any response with c#?  If you are not getting a response than the TLS authentication is failing which occurs before a request is sent.  The normal solution is to specify the TLS version : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: I think hes gettings response, Try and see what is the response Eg `result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized` And also this is Get request so you dont need to set `application/json` you are aready reading it as a string

Comment: Yes, Within "getTask" I'm getting the "result.IsSuccessStatusCode" as "false"

Comment: @Alen.Toma , The result of "result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized" is true.

Comment: Then you are doing somthing wrong with your Authorization. and there is the problem.

Comment: What would be wrong. Because the things I'm passing to ARC or postman passing the same things as headers.

Answer (score 0):

Your `AuthenticationHeaderValue` auth header will look like this when the request is sent:

```
Authorization: Authorization NLAuth nlauth_account=1249484_SKB1, nlauth_email=restletuser1@org.in, nlauth_signature=Breaths123!, nlauth_role=4444
```

As you can see the duplicate `Authorization` breaks it.

Instead use:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "NLAuth nlauth_account=1249484_SKB1, nlauth_email=restletuser1@org.in, nlauth_signature=Breaths123!, nlauth_role=4444");
```

As an aside you are really only supposed to create a single `HttpClient` instance and reuse it throughout the lifetime of your app.

Comment: When I implemented your code, it's throwing 400 status code, Bad request.

Comment: Run Fiddler and capture the raw request, something will be different when compared to the Postman post.

Comment: As I observed through quick watch in "client" object It's taking empty for "Authorization".

Comment: But, What you said is correct, About appending "Authorization" to the value.

Comment: When I tested with fiddler, I observed "Accept: application/json" But we need to pass it as "content-type".

Answer (score 0):

Your Auth should look like below

```
var authenticationHeaderValue = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("NLAuth", "nlauth_account=1249484_SKB1, nlauth_email=restletuser1@org.in, nlauth_signature=Breaths123!, nlauth_role=4444");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authenticationHeaderValue;
```

Or

```
var authenticationHeaderValue = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("NLAuth nlauth_account=1249484_SKB1, nlauth_email=restletuser1@org.in, nlauth_signature=Breaths123!, nlauth_role=4444");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authenticationHeaderValue;
```

There is already post on stackoverflow that cover this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312426/set-authorization-content-type-headers-when-call-httpclient-postasync)

Comment: Toma , The first one made to add header but giving 401 unauthorized response. The second one not even accepting as header, Instead throwing exception like format is invalid.